# How do I make a newly opened file the active window on GNOME 3?

Tags: nautilus, gnome-shell, window, focus

When I double click a file in Nautilus (e.g. a LibreOffice document) it will open a new window in the background, but Nautilus remains the active window.

Is there a way to open a file and have the new window automatically become the active window?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a GNOME shell extensions called [**NoAnnoyance**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/). This extension would put the newly launched window in focus straight away.

Read this to learn about installing and managing GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)

Comment: Thank You.
It worked like a charm.
I used the Ubuntu Software program, searched for noannoyance and installed it.
I've followed your other link about Gnome shell extensions and discovered how to turn the noannoyance extension off if I have to.

Comment: 18.04.LTS. IMHO It does not work if several monitors are used. If the application is opened on another monitor then this application does not get the focus. e.g. You use the dash to open an app and Ubuntu decides to open the application on a another monitor.